# iPhone:Error occurs while uploading image on twitter using sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter, sharekit

I am using sharekit to upload the image on twitter.
I have set keys and callback URL perfectly.

But after entering my login and password credentials
to upload image on twitter I got following error message.

**"There was a problem requesting access from Twitter."**

Earlier before few months in the same app I was able to upload
the image with same code.

But right now I am facing the problem

can you tell me what is the exact problem

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some changes occur in share kit. To resolve this issue. You have to change some piece of lines in `SHKTwitter.m`file under this method:

```
 - (void)tokenAccessModifyRequest:(OAMutableURLRequest *)oRequest
```

For detail info follow this link & make changes according to this link & then check:

```
https://github.com/SteveLeviathan/ShareKit/commit/7aab77655c1cbb1bf79092fcb3bb24dd80ab6380
```

UPDATE:

Replace your this method with my & then check:

```
- (void)tokenAccessModifyRequest:(OAMutableURLRequest *)oRequest
{   
    if (xAuth)
    {
        NSDictionary *formValues = [pendingForm formValues];

        OARequestParameter *username = [[[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"x_auth_username"
                                                                           value:[formValues objectForKey:@"username"]] autorelease];

        OARequestParameter *password = [[[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"x_auth_password"
                                                                           value:[formValues objectForKey:@"password"]] autorelease];

        OARequestParameter *mode = [[[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"x_auth_mode"
                                                                       value:@"client_auth"] autorelease];

        [oRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:username, password, mode, nil]];
    }

    else {
             if (self.pendingAction == SHKPendingRefreshToken)
                  {
                            if (accessToken.sessionHandle != nil)
                                   [oRequest setOAuthParameterName:@"oauth_session_handle" withValue:accessToken.sessionHandle];
                       }

                else
                        [oRequest setOAuthParameterName:@"oauth_verifier" withValue:[authorizeResponseQueryVars objectForKey:@"oauth_verifier"]];
            }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but as mentioned in url I wrote block of code but still I am getting same error.

Comment: I have one another issue after doing it also. It is "there was an error while sharing". Previously i am able to post the image on twitter

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to [ShareKit 2](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/) - it is being updated frequently.